# AIOGRAM (python) реакция

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота для поддержки пользователей в телеграмм.
Задача следующая - когда админ наживает кнопку взять вопрос, он автоматически ставит реакцию на сообщение, что бы другие пользователи на это сообщение уже не отвечали.
Вот как должно быть:
[image: Как это должно быть]

Как добавить кнопку я знаю, а вот команду для того что бы поставить реакцию нет :(

Answer (score 0):

В `aiogram` нет такого **метода**, но ты можешь почитать [тут](https://core.telegram.org/api/reactions) и реализовать это через **api**.

Comment: Привет! Спасибо за ответ, жаль не понимаю много чего ещё! 
Пытаюсь найти в том материале, что вы мне скинули и не понимаю ничего :(